# Nextjs 'endsWith' polyfill problem on edge and ie11

Tags: reactjs, next.js, microsoft-edge, polyfills

My site breaks and fails running because of the `Object doesn't support property or method 'endsWith'` error. I've tried polyfilling it with `import 'core-js/features/string/ends-with'` or

```js
if (!String.prototype.endsWith) {
  String.prototype.endsWith = function (search, this_len) {
    if (this_len === undefined || this_len > this.length) {
      this_len = this.length
    }
    return this.substring(this_len - search.length, this_len) === search
  }
}
```

I've done that in my custom `_app` file but it still fails in edge and ie11. What am I missing?

Edit: Judging by the https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/endsWith#Browser_compatibility `endsWith` should be supported in Edge

[image]

Comment: It looks like for external npm modules when you use it in your Next.js project, you have to add polyfill for those manually. You could refer to [this post](https://github.com/zeit/next.js/issues/7993#issuecomment-537530895) about solution for Next Js in IE 11 after adding polyfills.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add this to your code.

```
String.prototype.endsWith = function(pattern) {
  var d = this.length - pattern.length;
  return d >= 0 && this.lastIndexOf(pattern) === d;
};
```

Comment: I do not use endsWith anywhere, probably some dependency is. And as I said I included the polyfill in _app.js

Comment: As I said, i did that in the main entry file for the next.js app but it still throws the error